# How do I make Safari 7 load a Silverlight object which is the main content for the page?

Tags: silverlight, plugins, safari, osx-mavericks

With [OSX Maverick's "Power Saver" feature](http://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/), Safari 7 blocks plugin content in sidebars, but "if the content is front and center it plays as usual."

However, in the video player webapp I work on, it appears that Safari is blocking the Silverlight  from displaying -- and doesn't display the "click to play" banner on the element to activate it.  (For background knowledge, the web page creates the Silverlight object after detecting that Silverlight is supported and the best choice for the browser's capabilities.)

How should I indicate to Safari 7 that Silverlight  is the primary content of the page, or that it should have a banner?